# How To Embed CloverETL Design In a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, cloveretl

I am developing an Project which needs to implement an ETL tool, after some search i get to know that it is possible with CloverETL.

I Failed to get any reference regarding this, do anyone have any idea about how to do and start. I am unable to start.

[**CloverETL**](https://www.cloveretl.com)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you could transpone CloverETL Designer to web application easily. Designer is build on top of Eclipse platform, https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform , not sure if there is anything that could translate it easily.

There is a open source version of engine (internal java classes) that you could you use inside of your application, but you would need to build the UI yourself.